# Android, instead of creating a new activity, it creates an activity with fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am developing an Android app, and last week I updates a few packages (dont remember which ones exactly) using SDK Manager. After restarting Eclipse, whenever I create a new Activity (with used to contain only onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu methods), it creates an Activity with those two methods, plus the folowing code :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lmain,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I am new with Android so Im not sure why is that hapening and how to "undo" those changes in order to be able to create a "normal" Activity as before.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Android Studio and and yes, Android Studio does create one fragment and an extra method when you create your application..

It's not an issue,.. you can just delete that fragment.xml and that extra code that's with some condition and the whole additional method for the fragment.

Then it will be fine.. I don't know why exactly it happens in Android Studio.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, not Android Studio, but I managed to understand how to deal with it. You have to either do what you suggested or put everything that would be normally inside the Activity, into the Fragment. Thanks for the answer tho :)