# Android SDK creates FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430612/android-instead-of-creating-a-new-activity-it-creates-an-activity-with-fragmen) article but this article suggests replacing the FragmentActivity's code with that of the old Activity code. I can do that but would like to know if there's a way to just create Activity instead. I updated to ADT v22.6 today. Could that be the problem?

Another problem is that this requires a min-SDK of 7 while right now I want a min-SDK of 3.

Also, I am using Eclipse and not Android Studio.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using the question you have mentioned?

Comment: I just go to File->New->Android Activity and that creates a FragmentActivity now.. It used to create Activity earlier..

Comment: I am just trying to add a new activity..

Comment: You mean to say you are trying to create class in your project and that is creating FragmentActivity ?

Comment: There is not option of AndroidActivity in the `File>New>AndroidActivity` . It only creates New Android Application.

Comment: I mean File->New->Other->Android Activity.. Just the usual way to add a new activity to your project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `ADT 22.6` has new feature added that it will automatically create the any new activity as `FragmentActivity` not an single activity. So if you wish to create an `Activity` you can create it by explicitly creating separate class and extends Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that google is enforcing us to use fragments activities instead of plain activities now. You either can go back to an SDK previous to 22.6 or just create the activities by just extending the class, adding a layout and adding the activity reference to the manifest.